# document.onload without images or other elements (just HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to trigger a `document.onload` kinda event, but I want it to be triggered just when the HTML is completely loaded, without waiting for images or other elements.

I've been looking arround but I can't find something like that. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember a specific event for that, but you can trigger your event by putting this just before your last closing html tag:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        html_loaded(); // Custom function call
    </script>
</html>
```

That should work very effectively for any purpose.

HTH

Francisco

Answer (score 1):

You could just put a `<script>` tag with your code right at the bottom just before your `</body>` with the code to execute.

There's nothing to guarentee that images *won't* be loaded. But it certainly won't wait until they *are* loaded before it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).

(and just for the heck of it, but with jQuery: `$(document).ready(function () {});`)

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks. Unfortunately that's for HTML5 only.

Comment: @MaxPower And if you look at the MDN link I provided, there's a solution as a fallback for older browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded#Cross-browser_fallback

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event proposed by @Ian would work, but it is in the HTML5 specification and therefore would not be supported by legacy browsers like IE8.

Other wise I think @Chris Farmiloe's script solution is the best way to go.